# Eventlet heroku flasksocketio app not working

Tags: python, heroku, socket.io, gunicorn, flask-socketio

I'm Having lots of trouble deploying my Flask app that uses websockets to heroku. It works fine with `heroku local` and even works fine when the same command in run locally.

```
web:  gunicorn --worker-class eventlet --log-file=- app:app
```

The App is the same as the example here with very minimal changes: https://github.com/miguelgrinberg/Flask-SocketIO/blob/master/example/app.py

Here are the error logs:

```
2021-02-24T11:18:46.724927+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to up

2021-02-24T11:19:08.934471+00:00 app[web.1]: [2021-02-24 11:19:08 +0000] [4] [INFO] Shutting down: Master

2021-02-24T11:19:09.027108+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 0

2021-02-24T11:19:15.379018+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H13 desc="Connection closed without response" method=GET path="/" host=break1n.herokuapp.com request_id=f1d4ceac-69a1-43fc-a08d-c7462c6501fd fwd="122.181.58.194" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=17217ms status=503 bytes=0 protocol=https

2021-02-24T11:19:15.374389+00:00 app[web.1]: [2021-02-24 11:19:15 +0000] [4] [CRITICAL] WORKER TIMEOUT (pid:8)

2021-02-24T11:19:15.374534+00:00 app[web.1]: [2021-02-24 11:19:15 +0000] [4] [CRITICAL] WORKER TIMEOUT (pid:9)

2021-02-24T11:19:15.377083+00:00 app[web.1]: [2021-02-24 11:19:15 +0000] [9] [ERROR] Socket error processing request.

2021-02-24T11:19:15.377084+00:00 app[web.1]: Traceback (most recent call last):

2021-02-24T11:19:15.377084+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.8/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/base_async.py", line 65, in handle

2021-02-24T11:19:15.377085+00:00 app[web.1]:     util.reraise(*sys.exc_info())

2021-02-24T11:19:15.377085+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.8/site-packages/gunicorn/util.py", line 625, in reraise

2021-02-24T11:19:15.377086+00:00 app[web.1]:     raise value

2021-02-24T11:19:15.377086+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.8/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/base_async.py", line 38, in handle

2021-02-24T11:19:15.377086+00:00 app[web.1]:     listener_name = listener.getsockname()

2021-02-24T11:19:15.377087+00:00 app[web.1]: OSError: [Errno 9] Bad file descriptor

2021-02-24T11:19:15.377336+00:00 app[web.1]: [2021-02-24 11:19:15 +0000] [8] [ERROR] Socket error processing request.

2021-02-24T11:19:15.377336+00:00 app[web.1]: Traceback (most recent call last):

2021-02-24T11:19:15.377336+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.8/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/base_async.py", line 65, in handle

2021-02-24T11:19:15.377337+00:00 app[web.1]:     util.reraise(*sys.exc_info())

2021-02-24T11:19:15.377337+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.8/site-packages/gunicorn/util.py", line 625, in reraise

2021-02-24T11:19:15.377337+00:00 app[web.1]:     raise value

2021-02-24T11:19:15.377338+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.8/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/base_async.py", line 38, in handle

2021-02-24T11:19:15.377338+00:00 app[web.1]:     listener_name = listener.getsockname()

2021-02-24T11:19:15.377338+00:00 app[web.1]: OSError: [Errno 9] Bad file descriptor

2021-02-24T11:19:15.377724+00:00 app[web.1]: [2021-02-24 11:19:15 +0000] [9] [INFO] Worker exiting (pid: 9)

2021-02-24T11:19:15.378140+00:00 app[web.1]: [2021-02-24 11:19:15 +0000] [8] [ERROR] Socket error processing request.

2021-02-24T11:19:15.378141+00:00 app[web.1]: Traceback (most recent call last):

2021-02-24T11:19:15.378141+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.8/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/base_async.py", line 65, in handle

2021-02-24T11:19:15.378142+00:00 app[web.1]:     util.reraise(*sys.exc_info())

2021-02-24T11:19:15.378142+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.8/site-packages/gunicorn/util.py", line 625, in reraise

2021-02-24T11:19:15.378142+00:00 app[web.1]:     raise value

2021-02-24T11:19:15.378149+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.8/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/base_async.py", line 38, in handle

2021-02-24T11:19:15.378149+00:00 app[web.1]:     listener_name = listener.getsockname()

2021-02-24T11:19:15.378149+00:00 app[web.1]: OSError: [Errno 9] Bad file descriptor

2021-02-24T11:19:15.378747+00:00 app[web.1]: [2021-02-24 11:19:15 +0000] [8] [ERROR] Socket error processing request.

2021-02-24T11:19:15.378747+00:00 app[web.1]: Traceback (most recent call last):

2021-02-24T11:19:15.378748+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.8/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/base_async.py", line 65, in handle

2021-02-24T11:19:15.378748+00:00 app[web.1]:     util.reraise(*sys.exc_info())

2021-02-24T11:19:15.378748+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.8/site-packages/gunicorn/util.py", line 625, in reraise

2021-02-24T11:19:15.378749+00:00 app[web.1]:     raise value

2021-02-24T11:19:15.378749+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.8/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/base_async.py", line 38, in handle

2021-02-24T11:19:15.378749+00:00 app[web.1]:     listener_name = listener.getsockname()

2021-02-24T11:19:15.378749+00:00 app[web.1]: OSError: [Errno 9] Bad file descriptor

2021-02-24T11:19:15.379429+00:00 app[web.1]: [2021-02-24 11:19:15 +0000] [8] [INFO] Worker exiting (pid: 8)

2021-02-24T11:19:15.443250+00:00 app[web.1]: [2021-02-24 11:19:15 +0000] [10] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 10

2021-02-24T11:19:15.504260+00:00 app[web.1]: [2021-02-24 11:19:15 +0000] [11] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 11

2021-02-24T11:19:15.615154+00:00 app[web.1]: Staring Server........

2021-02-24T11:19:15.669596+00:00 app[web.1]: Staring Server........
```

Update:

I have tried all the deployment options in https://flask-socketio.readthedocs.io/en/latest/. Both gevent and eventlet don't seem to work

Comment: Try to deploy the app without gunicorn. After you successfuly did that try to run gunicorn locally. The app might not be compatible with gunicorn.

Comment: let me try that

Answer (score 0):

After following a suggestion, it was a problem with heroku and not gunicorn or eventlet. After fixing that , eventlet gunicorn wasn't cooperating. SO in the end for heroku I switched to uwsgi. Some incompatibility issue for ws on heroku with gunicorn.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried

```
web: gunicorn --worker-class eventlet -w 1 ...
```

I often run into errors when I don't set the `-w 1` option.